# How to get multitouch gestures on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, multi-touch

I just got a Dell XPS 14z that has a multi touch pad, and i want to get some gestures besides the two finger scrolling.
I've had some bad experiences with trying to figure things out by myself with ubuntu and i always end up messing something up and reinstalling, so i would like instructions, please.

Comment: check this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/142934/29470