# Missing mouse/touchpad options (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: mouse, touchpad, synaptics

It seems I've lost some of my mouse and touchpad settings:

[image: mouse touchpad settings problem ubuntu 16.04]

As it is, I can move the pointer with the touchpad, but there's no tap-to-click and it's set to non-natural two-finger scrolling.

So far, I've tried uninstalling/installing Synaptics touchpad driver, but no luck with that.

Does anyone know how can I get scrolling and click options back?

Comment: In ubuntu 16.04 LTS touchpad worked and Fn+F9 could enable/disable touchpad and I saw touchpad settings in "Mouse & Touchpad".
Recently I switched to ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS and I faced with the same issue.
I solved this by installing missing packages `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-libinput xorg-input-abi-22 xserver-xorg-core` from this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/778766/542791

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I found a solution to my issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215976/there-is-no-two-finger-scroll-option-in-my-mouse-and-touchpad-settings?rq=1), but here's a more concise explanation of what actually solved my issue:

Basically, I had to go to `/usr/shar/X11/xorg.conf.d` and edit the `50-synaptics.conf` file. Assuming root privileges, I opened this file in nano and added the following three lines under the third stanza, right below any already-listed `Option`:

```
Option "VertEdgeScroll" "1"
Option "TapButton2" "2"
Option "TapButton3" "3"
```

I then saved this as `90-synaptics.conf` and removed any competing libinput files. Rebooted, and got back tap-to-click, two-fingered right click, and edge scrolling (both vertical AND horizontal); exactly the same setup I had before.

From the Mouse and Touchpad settings menu, I regained everything but the ability to turn on/off horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on 19.10. It turned out that I didn't have the package xserver-xorg-input-synaptics installed. It turns out is doesn't have a chain of dependency from ubuntu-desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what did the trick in my Acer Nitro 5:

1. Go to the **BIOS setup**;
2. If there is no 'Touchpad' option in the 'main'
   tab, press Ctrl+S; it should instantly appear.
3. Select 'Touchpad' and change from PS2 to I2C;
4. Save and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+S did nothing.
How can I get to the Touchpad settings if the Touchpad has stopped operating and could be switched off?
What is the point of suggesting operations that involve a working Touchpad when it DOESN'T work?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! You seem to be making a comment in the answer section though, which risks your comment being downvoted or deleted. Please only provide solutions when you answer questions.