# Native touchpad and keyboard are unresponsive on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS running on a HP ProBook 640 G2

Tags: 22.04, keyboard, touchpad, hp, synaptics

My HP ProBook's (running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) touchpad and keyboard have been unresponsive for a while. As far as I can remember I haven't done any major updates. The problem started on the login page when I couldn't select user and enter password. However my wireless bluetooth mouse and keyboard work perfectly.
I've tried reinstalling the synaptics drivers, but that didn't help.
`xinput list` gives a wayland warning (which seems unrelated) but doesn't show my synaptics pointing device or keyboard in the connected input devices list either. I entered BIOS, but the touchpad is not there in the built-in device list either.
I tried the following solution (related to config files) but it's not working.
[Missing mouse/touchpad options (Ubuntu 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816982/missing-mouse-touchpad-options-ubuntu-16-04#817358)
[On-board keyboard and trackpad not working 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282260/on-board-keyboard-and-trackpad-not-working-20-04)

My `xinput list` result -

> WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
> Virtual core pointer                           id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
> ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
> ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                        id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
> ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16           id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
> ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16               id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
> Virtual core keyboard                      id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
> ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard    |          id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
> ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16           |          id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]

I've been trying various things for hours yet am stuck. Please help.

Comment: Is this working? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282260/on-board-keyboard-and-trackpad-not-working-20-04

Comment: @nobody I tried this and no, it isn't working either :(